# How to identify the cause of a process reading from disk at rates above 400 Mb/s

Tags: docker, container, azure, iotop

I am managing some virtual machines in Azure and a few times a week, at apparently random times, some of them start **I/O reading at speeds above 400 Mb/s**. This occurrs for one machine at a time, not simultaneously.

These machines use SSDs as hard drives, but those read speeds seem abnormal.

[image]

Additionally, the machines experiencing this activity **become unreachable via SSH after a few minutes**.

I am currently using **iotop** trying to output it to a log file, so after rebooting the stuck machine I can go through it and try to identify the process/es causing the trouble.

I am also using crontab to run it every minute.

Find below the current script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
OUT=/var/log/zs/io.log
echo $(date) >> $OUT
echo $(iotop -o -b -n 1|head -n 2) >> $OUT
echo $(iotop -o -b -n 1|head -n 6|tail -n +4) >> $OUT
```

And the log file showing the I/O peak:

```
Fri Jan 12 09:33:01 CET 2024
Total DISK READ : 113.45 M/s | Total DISK WRITE : 7.04 M/s Actual DISK READ: 171.85 M/s | Actual DISK WRITE: 85.79 M/s
3350 be/4 root 41.59 M/s 0.00 B/s ?unavailable? containerd 11744 be/4 root 112.49 M/s 0.00 B/s ?unavailable? dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock 11925 be/4 root 1142.56 K/s 0.00 B/s ?unavailable? dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
Fri Jan 12 09:58:35 CET 2024
```

Apparently it seems to be related to a docker process, but I would like to know:

1. Is it possible to prevent the machine from becoming unreachable?
2. How to track down the exact Docker container causing this trouble?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker should be able to set a limit to io operations, through its usage of cgroups (V2).

However, high disk write rates generally do *not* make a machine unresponsive via ssh.

My best guess here is that it's not a single docker container, but your operating system: you might have swap activated, and one of your containers is exploring in RAM usage.

Either way, this is something that should be pretty easy to figure out using your favorite process monitoring tool. `top` would do, but I do prefer `htop`, as it has the ability to show an Io read/write rate column as well.

You should use the same mechanic, cgroups integration of docker, to limit the amount of RAM a container can demand. Don't disable swap; that only makes matters worse, as you lose the flexibility to have a short term overdemand in RAM.